# Artifactory: getting HTTP 400 after unauthorized SAML log in attempt

Tags: saml, artifactory, adfs

I have SAML with ADFS configured in Artifactory and it is working just fine really. We are also "filtering" users by AD group membership and only allow users within a certain group to log in. All that is and has to be done by ADFS because Artifactory doesn't do that.

When a user is not authorized to log in with SAML he is redirected to an HTTP 400 Page though which obviously isn't a good solution. I can already see the tickets pouring in telling my that Artifactory doesn't work at all.

How can I avoid that or tell them actually what's the problem?

EDIT: using Artifactory version 5.3.1

Comment: Who is returning the 400, is it Artifactory? who is redirecting, Artifactory or the identity provider? do you see any error in the Artifactory log file?

Comment: The identity provider redirects to https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/webapp/saml/loginResponse as intended, but the user isn't authorized.

Artifactory has a samlException in the logs:[ERROR] (o.a.u.r.s.a.s.s.GetSamlLoginResponseService:55) - Failed to verify response signature
org.artifactory.addon.sso.saml.SamlException: Fail to find SAML Assertion in response.

Comment: This error indicates that Artifactory did not manage to verify the SAML response using the certificate provided in SAML settings. Make sure you are using the correct certificate.

Comment: Well, it does work when the user is actually allowed to log in. It shows that kind of behavior in case the user isn't allowed by ADFS